# When I try to scrape headless it gives me different results than when I want to scrape normally

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Basically, I want to Dockerize one of my scrapping app and when I try to add the headless options it doesn't give me the same results but I don't know what I can do to fix it.

The result I get when I try to scrape headlessly is (photo:  https://anonstories.com/no-image.jpeg

When I try to run it normally, it give me this: photo:  actual link of the image/video

I'm new to selenium and docker if anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

input_value = "cristiano"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get(f"https://anonstories.com/stories/{input_value}")

# Wait for elements with the specified class names
try:
    elements_4210945025 = WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "jsx-4210945025")))
except:
    elements_4210945025 = None

try:
    elements_2313292780 = WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "jsx-2313292780")))
except:
    elements_2313292780 = None

# Check and print "src" attribute for elements with the first class name
if elements_4210945025:
    i = 0
    while i < len(elements_4210945025):
        print("photo: ", elements_4210945025[i].get_attribute("src"))
        i += 1

# Check and print "src" attribute for elements with the second class name
if elements_2313292780:
    i = 0
    while i < len(elements_2313292780):
        print("video: ", elements_2313292780[i].get_attribute("src"))
        i += 1

# Check if any elements were found
if elements_4210945025 or elements_2313292780:
    name = 0
else:
    print("This profile is private or hasn't posted any stories")

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

and the result were this: photo:  https://anonstories.com/no-image.jpeg

When I try to run it normally, it give me this: photo:  actual link of the image/video

Comment: One simple workaround is to keep non headless, but use in `xvfb`. You will not have any window open. See https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml

Comment: The urls to images are dead. Please replace them